# Jboss | Unable to load certificate key

Tags: ssl, jboss, openssl, jboss7.x

```
JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
12:29:34,069 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
12:29:34,323 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) Error initializing endpoint: java.lang.Exception: Unable to load certificate key /mnt/jboss/kjockeystore (error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSLContext.setCertificate(Native Method) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.init(AprEndpoint.java:644) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol.init(Http11AprProtocol.java:121) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]

12:29:34,440 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.connector.https: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.connector.https: JBAS018007: Error starting web connector
        at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:271)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701) [rt.jar:1.6.0_27]
Caused by: LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.lang.Exception: Unable to load certificate key /mnt/jboss/kjockeystore (error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:985)
        at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267)
        ... 5 more

12:29:34,475 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--0.0.0.0-80
12:29:34,874 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on /0.0.0.0:9999
```

Connector tag used in Standalone.xml is below.

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" enable-lookups="true" secure="true">
                <ssl password="keystore@kjoc" certificate-key-file="/mnt/jboss/kjockeystore" verify-client="false" certificate-file="/mnt/jboss/WORKCOMP.KERLANJOBE.COM.key"/>
            </connector>
```

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Based on this line of your error: (error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line) the problem is that JBOSS is using native APR libraries. To make JBOSS use JRE libraries, in the subsystem you have to put **"native=false"**.

This answer is on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844844/https-on-jboss-as-7-1-2) which solved my problem..