# HTTPS on JBoss AS 7.1.2

Tags: jboss

I have followed the below link to setup HTTPS on jboss AS 7.1.2

http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=992

But after this when I start jboss, I get the following error:

```
10:31:05,481 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol]
        ↳ (MSC service thread 1-11) Error initializing endpoint: java.lang.Exception:
        ↳ Unable to load certificate key ../standalone/configuration/chap8.keystore
        ↳ (error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSLContext.setCertificate(Native Method) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.init(AprEndpoint.java:644) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol.init(Http11AprProtocol.java:121) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267) [jboss-as-web-7.1.2.Final.jar:7.1.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]

10:31:05,489 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-11)
        ↳ MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.connector.https:
        ↳ org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.connector.https:
        ↳ JBAS018007: Error starting web connector
    at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:271)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.lang.Exception:
        ↳ Unable to load certificate key ../standalone/configuration/chap8.keystore
        ↳ (error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:985)
    at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267)
    ... 5 more
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: I think the problem is with your keystore, have you created/generated it yourself?

Comment: yes i generated it myself by going into “keytool” utility which comes by default with the JDK and present inside the “$JAVA_HOME/bin” directory. http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=992

Comment: Try downloading KeyStore explorer and see if you can open de keystore successfully. Here is the link http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/. By the way if you have a certificate, you can use the KeyStore  explorer to import it and create the key/trust-stores easily. Hopefully your CN is also correctly assigned e.g. cn=hostname in the certificate.

Comment: I am having trouble installing keystore-explorer...                   It asks me to download some unlimited packages and when I click on the button, I get the following error....                                  **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Desktop API is not supported on the current platform
 at java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop(Desktop.java:144)**

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the above error since JBoss was using *native APR libraries*. The issue is solved by making JBoss use *JSE libraries* instead of native APR libraries.

Use **native="false"** in the subsystem tag to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question was added over year ago, but someone might find this answer helpful.
You are using org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol protocol, which uses native OpenSSL. Provided certificate (basing on file extension) is JKS keystore. OpenSSL cannot read this format and therefore throws `error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line`. In order to resolve this you must convert your keystore to OpenSSL compliant format (crt, pem, key) or generate new keys etc. using OpenSSL. There is also some configuration differences. Refer to this [JBoss docs](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/config/ssl.html). This works on Jboss AS 7.3.2, but as far as I know there is no difference between 7.1.2 and 7.3.2 in this matter.